# Browser tab and bookmark bar font is too small

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, browser, opera

[Chrome and Opera browsers side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2DCi.png)

I've had this issue for months now and it has been driving me mental. Ever few weeks after installing an update the font sizes in my browsers (both chrome and Opera) change sizes and they're independant of each other. I've had Chrome being normal and Opera's fonts being wacky and vice versa. Sometimes the fonts are huge and I can only see a few letters in the tabs. Other times they're miniscule, like now.

I just restarted my system and now they're BOTH tiny.

I've uninstalled and re-installed. I've googled everything. All I can find is a bunch of other people complaining about the same issue in Chrome with no solution.

I'm going nuts with this issue, does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: What graphics hardware and driver?  Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration in the browsers?

Comment: Nvidia GTX 1060. It's happened with the last 3 drivers from Nvidia. Yes hardware acceleration is disabled.

Incidentally I had a random powercut a day ago. When I started my machine up again the fonts were larger. Not normal, but at least readable.

I had rebooted my machine multiple times before that with no effect.

I still really want to know what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu. Edit file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/opera.desktop
```

and followed your code replacements...

Find the line

```
Exec=opera %U
```

And replace with

```
Exec=opera --force-device-scale-factor=1 %U
```

Restart opera.

The solution is from:
[Font size of bookmarks and tabs got small for chrome in ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907095/font-size-of-bookmarks-and-tabs-got-small-for-chrome-in-ubuntu-16-04)